# QnA Maker doesn't recognise links using markup language

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

We have been using QnA Maker for months and today we have detected that from today, maybe yesterday the markup language we are using for links inside the answers is not working fine.

We have detected that when the pair is inside the "Editorial" group doesn't work but if it's inside a group like XXX.tsv it works fine. This happens when we replace the KB from an existing service. If we create a new one with the same tsv (export --> import) it works fine.

We have used this process at least 50-60 times and always has worked fine.

How to reproduce the error:

1. Create a new service with some KB you have with pairs
2. Add some new pair manually (it will go to Editorial group) with markup in answer like: "answer [link](https://www.micfrosoft.com).
3. Test it directly in the console --> it will work
4. Export the KB
5. Import in the same KB
6. Test again --> it will not work

Workaround

1. Open the TSV exported
2. Replace editorial with something like "questions.tsv"
3. Import in the previous used service
4. Test it --> it will work

Any idea?

Vicens

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: The problem is not the channel, is the own QnA portal. If you test it using the own test tool of the portal you can see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Working again. Issue solved by MS.